# For-loop not working the way i want it to

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, hashtable

I have a extremely minor issue that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to extract data based on a type of value from an ArrayList> and place it into another ArrayList.  The issue is that the for-loop only runs once, which in this case i need it to traverse the entire array and then place the data into the unSuppressedData arraylist.
Below is the for-loop:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < suppressedStatus.length; x++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < availData.size(); i++) {
        Hashtable<String,String> checkAvail = availData.get(i);
        String itemStatus = checkAvail.get("loanStatus");
        if (unSuppressedData.contains(checkAvail) == false) {
            if (!(itemStatus.equals(suppressedStatus[x]))) {
                Log.d("Item Status", itemStatus);
                Log.d("Suppressed Status", suppressedStatus[x]);
                unSuppressedData.add(checkAvail);
                //break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

suppressedStatus is a String array
availData is the arraylist i want to extract data from
unSuppressedData is the arraylist i want to place the data in

I believe that it only runs once is due to this line of code:

```
 if (unSuppressedData.contains(checkAvail) == false) {
```

But i need to this line to check whether my unSuppressdData has the data, if no then will add the data from availData arraylist into unSuppressedData arraylist.

Could it be that i'm writing this piece of code wrongly? Appreciate any insights shed on this.

Comment: What's the type of `unsuppressedData`? It's quite unusual to pass a hashtable to `contains`.

Comment: unsupprressedData is a arraylist<hashtable<string,String>>

Answer (score 0):

A good collection type for this sort of thing is the LinkedHashSet. Because it's a set, each element can only be added once. Being a hash, the contains test is quick. Being 'linked' the resulting set is iterated in insertion order.

Comment: Hmm.. Mind explaining further?

Comment: The [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) probably describes it better an I would. Basically it's exactly like a HashSet except any iteration over the collection is in insertion order.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to add the wanted data from availData to unSuppressedData arraylist which is empty. LinkHashSet can do that?

Comment: Yes use LinkedHashSet for unSuppressedData and you don't need a contains check since it doesn't store duplicates. When done iteraing through this collection will be in same order the elements were first inserted.

Comment: thanks. by using ur suggestion i dun have any more duplicate elements anymore. But i have another question. How can i retrieve the hashtable values of the arraylist from the linkedhashset? How can i then place the data into textviews? Please help. i'm very close to clearing this hurdle.